# Host Selenium(eclipse) and application on citrix and run Automation Test's

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automation, citrix

Is there a way by which we can we host eclipse(with selenium) and application on which we want to run automation test's both on citrix and run the scripts via citrix itself?

Currently our project cannot afford more remote machines, but they have a need in which all the functional tester's should be able to run Automation scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can run automation scripts in virtual machine..

Executing selenium automation scripts in virtual machine is same as executing in physical machine..

If you want eclipse and selenium configured already in your Citrix vdi, then I suggest you to contact your system admin of your company to configure the same in one machine and create a snap shot of that machine..then whenever you provision a new virtual machine then your selenium and eclipse would have been already configured..